React, Nextjs Error: Element type is invalid
I have had this error and I have not known how to solve it after searching a lot to see if someone can help me.
Error
Main page
// src/app/pages.js
import Intro from '@/components/landing/Intro'
import Bento from '@/components/landing/Bento'
import Fuentes from '@/components/landing/Fuentes'
import SkeletonBento from '@/components/skeletons/BentoSkeleton'
import AboutLanding from '@/components/landing/AboutLanding'
import { Suspense } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Intro />
      <Suspense fallback={<SkeletonBento />}>
        <Bento />
      </Suspense>
      <Fuentes />
      <AboutLanding />
    </>
  )
}

Error Page
//app/components/landing/Fuentes.js
'use client'
import CardFuentes from './CardFuentes'
import Carousel from 'react-multi-carousel'
import 'react-multi-carousel/lib/styles.css'
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

function CustomDot({ onClick, ...rest }) {
  const { active } = rest

  const activeStyle = 'h-2 w-2 bg-[#FFD700] rounded-full'
  const inactiveStyle = 'h-2 w-2 bg-gray-400 rounded-full'

  return (
    <li>
      <button
        type="button"
        aria-label="Dot"
        onClick={onClick}
        style={{
          display: 'inline-block',
          margin: '0 8px',
        }}
      >
        <div className={`${active ? activeStyle : inactiveStyle} `}></div>
      </button>
    </li>
  )
}

function Fuentes() {
  const delays = [1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
  const cardData = [
    { image: '/aemet.webp', title: 'Agencia Estatal de Meteorología' },
    {
      image: '/miteco.webp',
      title: 'Ministerio para la Transición Ecológica y el Reto Demográfico',
    },
    { image: '/sahi.webp', title: 'Sistema Automático de Información Hidrológica' },
    { image: '/embalsesnet.webp', title: 'Embalses.net' },
  ]

  const containerVariants = {
    initial: {},
    animate: {
      transition: {
        staggerChildren: 0.2,
      },
    },
  }

  const childVariants = (delay) => ({
    initial: { opacity: 0, y: 50 },
    animate: { opacity: 1, y: 0, transition: { delay } },
  })

  const responsive = {
    superLargeDesktop: {
      breakpoint: { max: 4000, min: 3000 },
      items: 5,
    },
    desktop: {
      breakpoint: { max: 3000, min: 1024 },
      items: 3,
    },
    tablet: {
      breakpoint: { max: 1294, min: 464 },
      items: 2,
    },
    mobile: {
      breakpoint: { max: 464, min: 0 },
      items: 1,
    },
  }

  return (
    <section
      id="fuentes"
      className="h-auto bg-bgcolor"
    >
      <article className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
        <motion.h1
          initial="initial"
          variants={{
            initial: { opacity: 0, x: 50 },
            animate: { opacity: 1, x: 0, transition: { duration: 0.5 } },
          }}
          whileInView="animate"
          viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.8 }}
          className="font-telma pt-1 text-center text-[40px] text-[#ffd700] sm:pt-20 sm:text-[50px]"
        >
          Fuentes Oficiales
        </motion.h1>

        <motion.div
          initial="initial"
          variants={{
            initial: { width: 0 },
            animate: { width: '100%', transition: { duration: 0.5, delay: 0.5 } },
          }}
          whileInView="animate"
          viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.8 }}
          className="mt-2 flex w-full justify-center border-y border-[hsl(237,50%,20%)] py-6 text-2xl text-textprimary sm:py-10"
        >
          <motion.h1
            initial="initial"
            variants={{
              initial: { opacity: 0, scale: 0 },
              animate: { opacity: 1, scale: 1, transition: { duration: 0.3, delay: 1 } },
            }}
            whileInView="animate"
            viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.8 }}
            className="mx-3 text-center"
          >
            Datos Actualizados Cada{' '}
            <strong className="ml-2 content-center text-[#ffd700]">6 horas</strong>
          </motion.h1>
        </motion.div>
      </article>

      <motion.div
        className="m-auto mt-10 sm:w-[35rem] md:w-[40rem] lg:w-[60rem] xl:w-[80rem]"
        variants={containerVariants}
        initial="initial"
        whileInView="animate"
        viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.8 }}
      >
        <Carousel
          responsive={responsive}
          infinite={true}
          autoPlay={true}
          autoPlaySpeed={2000}
          showDots={true}
          arrows={false}
          ssr={true}
          customDot={<CustomDot />}
        >
          {cardData.map((card, index) => (
            <motion.div
              key={card.title}
              className="flex justify-center"
              variants={childVariants(delays[index])}
              viewport={{ once: true, amount: 0.8 }}
            >
              <CardFuentes
                image={card.image}
                title={card.title}
              />
            </motion.div>
          ))}
        </Carousel>
      </motion.div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Fuentes

Carousel from react-multi-carousel
import * as React from "react";
export interface ResponsiveType {
    [key: string]: {
        breakpoint: {
            max: number;
            min: number;
        };
        items: number;
        partialVisibilityGutter?: number;
        paritialVisibilityGutter?: number;
        slidesToSlide?: number;
    };
}
export declare function isMouseMoveEvent(e: React.MouseEvent | React.TouchEvent): e is React.MouseEvent;
export interface CarouselProps {
    responsive: ResponsiveType;
    deviceType?: string;
    ssr?: boolean;
    slidesToSlide?: number;
    draggable?: boolean;
    arrows?: boolean;
    renderArrowsWhenDisabled?: boolean;
    swipeable?: boolean;
    removeArrowOnDeviceType?: string | Array<string>;
    children: any;
    customLeftArrow?: React.ReactElement<any> | null;
    customRightArrow?: React.ReactElement<any> | null;
    customDot?: React.ReactElement<any> | null;
    customButtonGroup?: React.ReactElement<any> | null;
    infinite?: boolean;
    minimumTouchDrag?: number;
    afterChange?: (previousSlide: number, state: StateCallBack) => void;
    beforeChange?: (nextSlide: number, state: StateCallBack) => void;
    sliderClass?: string;
    itemClass?: string;
    itemAriaLabel?: string;
    containerClass?: string;
    className?: string;
    dotListClass?: string;
    keyBoardControl?: boolean;
    centerMode?: boolean;
    autoPlay?: boolean;
    autoPlaySpeed?: number;
    showDots?: boolean;
    renderDotsOutside?: boolean;
    renderButtonGroupOutside?: boolean;
    partialVisible?: boolean;
    partialVisbile?: boolean;
    customTransition?: string;
    transitionDuration?: number;
    focusOnSelect?: boolean;
    additionalTransfrom?: number;
    pauseOnHover?: boolean;
    shouldResetAutoplay?: boolean;
    rewind?: boolean;
    rewindWithAnimation?: boolean;
    rtl?: boolean;
}
export declare type StateCallBack = CarouselInternalState;
export declare type Direction = "left" | "right" | "" | undefined;
export declare type SkipCallbackOptions = boolean | {
    skipBeforeChange?: boolean;
    skipAfterChange?: boolean;
};
export interface ButtonGroupProps {
    previous?: () => void;
    next?: () => void;
    goToSlide?: (index: number, skipCallbacks?: SkipCallbackOptions) => void;
    carouselState?: StateCallBack;
}
export interface ArrowProps {
    onClick?: () => void;
    carouselState?: StateCallBack;
}
export interface DotProps {
    index?: number;
    active?: boolean;
    onClick?: () => void;
    carouselState?: StateCallBack;
}
export interface CarouselInternalState {
    itemWidth: number;
    containerWidth: number;
    slidesToShow: number;
    currentSlide: number;
    totalItems: number;
    domLoaded: boolean;
    deviceType?: string;
    transform: number;
}
export default class Carousel extends React.Component<CarouselProps> {
    previous: (slidesHavePassed: number) => void;
    next: (slidesHavePassed: number) => void;
    goToSlide: (slide: number, skipCallbacks?: SkipCallbackOptions) => void;
    state: CarouselInternalState;
    setClones: (slidesToShow: number, itemWidth?: number, forResizing?: boolean) => void;
    setItemsToShow: (shouldCorrectItemPosition?: boolean) => void;
    correctClonesPosition: ({ domLoaded }: {
        domLoaded: boolean;
    }) => void;
    onMove: boolean;
    direction: Direction;
    containerRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>;
}

As I said, I have been looking for a solution, I have checked the imports, deleted part of the code to find the error, and the only way I have had that the error disappears is deleting the Carrousel component, I have also tried to download another package of sliders and gave me the same error, something strange.
I hope someone can help me.

Fixed removing type : "module" from package json
